# Сreate pan under arc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-reanimated

[image]

I've added a basic radius creation, how do I relate that to panning?

```
const strokeWidth = 10;
const size = width - 32;

const { PI, cos, sin } = Math;

const cy = size / 2;
const cx = size / 2;
const A = Math.PI * PI * 0.4;
const startAngle = PI + PI * 0.2;
const endAngle = 2 * PI - PI * 0.2;
const r = (size - strokeWidth) / 2;
const startX = cx - r * cos(startAngle);
const startY = -r * sin(startAngle) + cy;

const endX = cx - r * cos(endAngle);
const endY = -r * sin(endAngle) + cy;

const d = `M ${startX} ${startY} A ${r} ${r} 0 1 0 ${endX} ${endY}`;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you mean moving the button (<>) around the arc?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.